# Microsoft Bot Framework for Skype do not works for other users

Tags: frameworks, skype, botframework

I've made Bot for Skype with Microsoft Bot Framework
The bot was registered on MS site (now in the review status).
It answered on my messages in the Skype.

when I share it to other users the Skype shows for them:
**Messaging unavailable.**

Could somebody give me some direction how to found where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on how many other users.

Initially Skype will have your bot in a pending state which limits your bot to 100 users.  You can go to the Skype bot portal and request that your bot be elevated from that initial status.

If however nobody can get to your bot I would consider:

1. Do they have the latest skype client with support for bots?
2. Maybe there's something going on with the bot framework.

If you think the latter, you can send us your bot id at bf-reports@microsoft.com and we can investigate.

--jim